# MVVM View - ViewModel communication through events

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm

Edit: I have reworked my question because I seemed a bit to lazy.

Edit2: Updated the code, forgot 1 thing and wrote EventArg instead of UserInputEventArgs at ViewUcBase.UserInputErrorHandler

Edit3: Changed VMBase, still not working tough.

So I have this (partial) current setup: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ibsbwv2faigxal/MVVM%20Messaging.png?dl=0

And now I want to do the following things:

- Define an event (UserInputError) in IViewModelComponent that can be
  raised by any specific View Model (supplying a string that tells the
  consumer of the event what went wrong).
- Have a virtual (default) Consumer in ViewBase that just shows a Messagebox with the error string.
- Have the constructor of ViewBase subscribe its handler to the event. So that the Specific views don't have to think about this.

Considerations:

- I know there are frameworks out there that easily do this for you. But I like to know how stuff works before I use something that does it for me, at least on a base model.
- Edit: I got my inspiration for this from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec12
- I have a basic understanding of events based on : "How to: Raise and Consume Event" on msdn (sorry only 2 links possible) and I have gotten it to work in a simple project before.
- I have no problem with code behind as long as it only does view tasks.

The code that isn't working. I know I'm missing something, but can't seem to find what. (error at the end)

```
    public interface IViewModelComponent
    {
        event EventHandler UserInputError;

        //just to show I want multiple events.
        event EventHandler SomeOtherEvent;
    }

    public class VMBase: IViewModelComponent
    {
        public event EventHandler<UserInputEventArgs> UserInputError;
        protected virtual void OnUserInputError(UserInputEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<UserInputEventArgs> handler = UserInputError;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        //just to show I want multiple events.
        public event EventHandler SomeOtherEvent;
        ...
    }

    public class UserInputEventArgs: EventArgs
    {
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }

    public class AssetForm : VMBase
    {
        private void SomethingBadHappened()
        {
            UserInputEventArgs args = new UserInputEventArgs;
            args.ErrorMessage = "This bad thing hapened";
            OnUserInputError(args);
        }
    }

    public class ViewUcBase : UserControl, IViewComponent
    {
        //EDIT: Forgot the next line
        public IViewModelComponent VM { get; set; }

        //Default implementation of what should be done with the event.
        public virtual void UserInputErrorHandler(object sender, UserInputEventArgs e)
        {
            string header = string.Format("{0} - InputError",DisplayName);
            MessageBox.Show(e.ErrorMessage,header,MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        }

        //Subscribing to the event in the base class so it always gets handled.
        public ViewUcBase()
        {
            VM.UserInputError += UserInputErrorHandler; //No overload for 'UserInputErrorHandler' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'
        }
    }
```

}

I hope this update explains things better, and that I haven't missed anything.

Comment: *I can't get this to work* is a very poor description of your errors. *•I am not giving any code because I want an answer that is as clean as possible*... we are *not* here to do your work for you... YOU need to make some effort and show it here. -1

Comment: Update the question accordingly. I'm sorry I didn't include code before, but I have seen some code postings here that completly missed what the poster was trying to do. Since this seems to cause confusion, I tried to put my problems into words as best as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I use the ***Publish Subscribe pattern*** for complicated class-dependencies:

**ViewModel:**

```
    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            CloseComand = new DelegateCommand((obj) =>
                {
                    MessageBus.Instance.Publish(Messages.REQUEST_DEPLOYMENT_SETTINGS_CLOSED, null);
                });
        }
}
```

**Window:**

```
public partial class SomeWindow : Window
{
    Subscription _subscription = new Subscription();

    public SomeWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _subscription.Subscribe(Messages.REQUEST_DEPLOYMENT_SETTINGS_CLOSED, obj =>
            {
                this.Close();
            });
    }
}
```

You can leverage [Bizmonger.Patterns](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bizmonger.Patterns/1.0.0) to get the MessageBus.

**MessageBus**

```
public class MessageBus
{
    #region Singleton
    static MessageBus _messageBus = null;
    private MessageBus() { }

    public static MessageBus Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_messageBus == null)
            {
                _messageBus = new MessageBus();
            }

            return _messageBus;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Members
    List<Observer> _observers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _oneTimeObservers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _waitingSubscribers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _waitingUnsubscribers = new List<Observer>();

    int _publishingCount = 0;
    #endregion

    public void Subscribe(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        Subscribe(message, response, _observers);
    }

    public void SubscribeFirstPublication(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        Subscribe(message, response, _oneTimeObservers);
    }

    public int Unsubscribe(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Respond == response).ToList());
        observers.AddRange(_waitingSubscribers.Where(o => o.Respond == response));
        observers.AddRange(_oneTimeObservers.Where(o => o.Respond == response));

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.ForEach(o => _observers.Remove(o));
        }

        else
        {
            _waitingUnsubscribers.AddRange(observers);
        }

        return observers.Count;
    }

    public int Unsubscribe(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription).ToList());
        observers.AddRange(_waitingSubscribers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));
        observers.AddRange(_oneTimeObservers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.ForEach(o => _observers.Remove(o));
        }

        else
        {
            _waitingUnsubscribers.AddRange(observers);
        }

        return observers.Count;
    }

    public void Publish(string message, object payload)
    {
        _publishingCount++;

        Publish(_observers, message, payload);
        Publish(_oneTimeObservers, message, payload);
        Publish(_waitingSubscribers, message, payload);

        _oneTimeObservers.RemoveAll(o => o.Subscription == message);
        _waitingUnsubscribers.Clear();

        _publishingCount--;
    }

    private void Publish(List<Observer> observers, string message, object payload)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_publishingCount >= 0);

        var subscribers = observers.Where(o => o.Subscription.ToLower() == message.ToLower());

        foreach (var subscriber in subscribers)
        {
            subscriber.Respond(payload);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Observer> GetObservers(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));
        return observers;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _observers.Clear();
        _oneTimeObservers.Clear();
    }

    #region Helpers
    private void Subscribe(string message, Action<object> response, List<Observer> observers)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_publishingCount >= 0);

        var observer = new Observer() { Subscription = message, Respond = response };

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.Add(observer);
        }
        else
        {
            _waitingSubscribers.Add(observer);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

**Subscription**

```
public class Subscription
{
    #region Members
    List<Observer> _observerList = new List<Observer>();
    #endregion

    public void Unsubscribe(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = _observerList.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription);

        foreach (var observer in observers)
        {
            MessageBus.Instance.Unsubscribe(observer.Subscription, observer.Respond);
        }

        _observerList.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription).ToList().ForEach(o => _observerList.Remove(o));
    }

    public void Subscribe(string subscription, Action<object> response)
    {
        MessageBus.Instance.Subscribe(subscription, response);
        _observerList.Add(new Observer() { Subscription = subscription, Respond = response });
    }

    public void SubscribeFirstPublication(string subscription, Action<object> response)
    {
        MessageBus.Instance.SubscribeFirstPublication(subscription, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Link only answers are not appreciated on Stack Overflow. Please copy the relevant sections here.

Comment: Why use Event Aggregation? Nothing wrong with using plain old .NET Events! The View will always have a reference to the viewmodel anyway so subscribing is a non issue. Seems to me that as soon as someone discovers event aggregation they go out of their way to find reasons to use it.

Comment: Not really what I am looking for, since I am looking for a 1 to 1 ratio on raiser/consumer.

Comment: @Ben I find that whenever I need to notify multiple view models and/or modules accross my application, leveraging a pattern like this tends to work for me. I'm surprise plain-old dot net events have always been the tool of choice for your applications.

Comment: They have not but in this scenario they do not make any sense. Event Aggregation is great when uncoupled view models need to be notified of an event however what the OP wants is a simple basic event scenario so he can understand whats happening which made your answer seem odd.

Comment: It's useful for me!

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was something stupid, and it was.

I was mixing 2 examples from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. So I updated all the

```
    "Eventhandler" to "EventHandler<UserInputEventArgs>"
```

and it is working now.

Sorry for wasting your time.

The complete working code:

```
    public interface IViewModelComponent
    {
        event EventHandler<UserInputEventArgs> UserInputError;
    }

    public class VMBase: IViewModelComponent
    {
        public event EventHandler<UserInputEventArgs> UserInputError;
        protected virtual void OnUserInputError(UserInputEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<UserInputEventArgs> handler = UserInputError;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    public class UserInputEventArgs: EventArgs
    {
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }

    public class AssetForm : VMBase
    {
        private void SomethingBadHappened()
        {
            UserInputEventArgs args = new UserInputEventArgs;
            args.ErrorMessage = "This bad thing hapened";
            OnUserInputError(args);
        }
    }

    public class ViewUcBase : UserControl, IViewComponent
    {
        //EDIT: Forgot the next line
        public IViewModelComponent VM { get; set; }

        //Default implementation of what should be done with the event.
        public virtual void UserInputErrorHandler(object sender, UserInputEventArgs e)
        {
            string header = string.Format("{0} - InputError",DisplayName);
            MessageBox.Show(e.ErrorMessage,header,MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        }

        //Subscribing to the event in the base class so it always gets handled.
        public ViewUcBase()
        {
            VM.UserInputError += UserInputErrorHandler; //No overload for 'UserInputErrorHandler' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'
        }
    }
```

}